# AVAudioEngine separate channels

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-audio, avaudioengine

I have a stereo audio file for which I try to separate the audio channels. Resulting in a bus with the left audio, and a bus with the right audio signal. On these channels I want to do some operations and then merge them again to a single stereo signal.

Reading the audio file, doing operations on the bus and merging it to a single signal is no problem (though I haven't tested if this signal is stereo, as it depends on the prior channels I guess).

My problem is in separating the left and the right channel, so I can independently modify them.

One of my ideas was to use the `pan`property of `AVAudioPlayerNode` to have the signal only left/right, but it seems like (as mentioned in the documentation) this property is not yet implemented in the `AVAudioPlayerNode` (Even though in all the examples of the WWDC videos it is used).

Another solution I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27250317/avaudioengine-playing-multi-channel-audio). Using `memcpy` to create new buffers. I haven't tried this yet as I guess this takes quite some time and is not suitable for a normal player.

Third there is a framework called [audiokit](http://audiokit.io/). This provides the option of converting the stream to mono left/right channel and then merging the signal again by creating an `AKStereoOperation`. My problem with this solution is, it is quite a simple use-case. Separating the audio channels. For this I find it hard to justify including such a huge framework, even though it would probably work (not tested).

Is there a simple way to separate the channels?

Thanks!

Comment: were you able to ever combine the 2 mono streams back into a single stereo stream?

Comment: sadly not with avaudioengine. with audiokit it is possible

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using objective C for my project, and I think AudioKit is only for Swift.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the raw samples and create an `AudioConverter` using `AudioConverterNew` with and output `AudioStreamBasicDescription` configured to de-interleave the stereo channels. This will result in one buffer with one channel contiguously first and the second channel in the second half of the buffer.

Comment: can we still use AudioConverter if we aren't trying to change the file format? In my case, I'm trying to combine 2 mono CAF files with same sample rate and length into a single stereo file. Is there sample code for AudioConverterNew that shows you how to set the formatting?

Comment: Yes. The `AudioConverter` documentation lists the conversions that it supports. I believe there is an Apple sample showing how to use it, but I don't have a link handy.

Comment: I'm looking at the documentation for AudioConverterNew here https://developer.apple.com/reference/audiotoolbox/1502936-audioconverternew?language=objc. There are 3 parameters for this function however the inSourceFormat seems to suggest that it is only taking in a singular source file. However, in my case, I have 2 separate audio files with unique mono streams. I'm clearly missing something here unfortunately there's not a whole lot of documentation on the Apple site.

Comment: `AudioConverter` does not work on files. It works on buffers of data. Those buffers may come from files, it is up to you to provide them.

Comment: Sounds good, I guess the approach now is to figure out how to take my input files and extract the buffers and then non-interleave them into a single output buffer. When I work with these input buffers, do I need to be concerned about headers?

Comment: @A21 Did you ever find out how to do this?