# AVAudioPlayerNode multichannel audio control

Tags: swift, mono, core-audio, surround, avaudiopcmbuffer

I have successfully used `AVAudioPlayerNode` to play stereo and mono files. I would like to use files with 3+ channels (surround files) and be able to route the audio in a non-linear way. For instance, I could assign file channel 0 to output channel 2, and file channel 4 to output channel 1.

The number of outputs of the audio interface will be unknown (2-40), and this is why I need to be able to allow the user to route the audio as they see fit. And the solution in [WWDC 2015 507](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/507/?time=372) of having the user change the routing in Audio Midi Setup is not a viable solution.

There's only 1 possibility that I can think of (and I am open to others): creating one player per channel, and loading each with only one channels' worth of buffers [similar to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27250317/avaudioengine-playing-multi-channel-audio/27274781#27274781). But even by the posters admission, there are issues.

So I'm looking for a way to copy each channel of a file into an AudioBuffer like:

```
let file = try AVAudioFile(forReading: audioURL)
let fullBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: file.processingFormat, 
                                  frameCapacity: AVAudioFrameCount(file.length))

try file.read(into: fullBuffer)

// channel 0
let buffer0 = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: file.processingFormat,
                               frameCapacity: AVAudioFrameCount(file.length))

// this doesn't work, unable to get fullBuffer channel and copy
// error on subscripting mBuffers
buffer0.audioBufferList.pointee.mBuffers.mData = fullBuffer.audioBufferList.pointee.mBuffers[0].mData

// repeat above buffer code for each channel from the fullBuffer
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out, so here's the code to make it work. Note: the code below separates a stereo (2 channel) file. This could easily be expanded to handle an unknown number of channels.

```
let file = try AVAudioFile(forReading: audioURL)

let formatL = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32, sampleRate: file.processingFormat.sampleRate, channels: 1, interleaved: false)
let formatR = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32, sampleRate: file.processingFormat.sampleRate, channels: 1, interleaved: 

let fullBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: file.processingFormat, frameCapacity: AVAudioFrameCount(file.length))
let bufferLeft = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: formatL, frameCapacity: AVAudioFrameCount(file.length))
let bufferRight = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: formatR, frameCapacity: AVAudioFrameCount(file.length))

try file.read(into: fullBuffer)
bufferLeft.frameLength = fullBuffer.frameLength
bufferRight.frameLength = fullBuffer.frameLength

for i in 0..<Int(file.length) {
    bufferLeft.floatChannelData![0][i] = fullBuffer.floatChannelData![0][i]
    bufferRight.floatChannelData![0][i] = fullBuffer.floatChannelData![1][i]
}
```